# Get count of second table along with the id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a scenario I have table named groups and forums. Within in that group I WANTED to show 5 groups with maximum forums created within that group in descending order. Now the problem is that I have the count of how many forums are posted in each group, now main issue is I am confused how to get the data of that group. Can anyone help me out ?

```
<?php
    $sql_gr_coun = $this->db->query("SELECT groups.*, (SELECT count(group_id) FROM forums WHERE groups.id = forums.group_id) as forumcount FROM groups ORDER BY forumcount DESC LIMIT 5");
    foreach($sql_gr_coun->result() as $data_count):
         $sql_grp = $this->db->get_where('groups', array('id' => $data_count->group_id));
    endforeach;
 ?>


Groups
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | group 1  |
| 2  | group 2  |
| 3  | group 3  |
| 4  | group 4  |
+----+----------+

forums
+------------------+-------------+
| id | title       | group_id    |
+------------------+-------------+
| 1  | test 1      |           2 |
| 2  | test 2      |           3 |
| 3  | test 3      |           2 |
| 4  | test 4      |           3 |
| 5  | test 5      |           2 |
| 6  | test 6      |           4 |
+------------------+-------------+
```

As of I am unable to get the data of the groups now how do i do that

Comment: get the group id, send it to some model function and return the data

Comment: how do i get group id in which there are the forums more like going through loops first groups id counted 3 and second group id counted 2 so how to get 3 forums groups info and 2 forums group info ?

Comment: can you share your db schema. ? your table structure?

Comment: have you printed this by print_r or dump?

Comment: when you are writing this in your query SELECT groups.*, you are already getting group data along with ID , what else do you want

Comment: OOOHHH mine how fool I am sorry thank you so much please post this in your answer I GOT MY ANSWER when i used var_dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are writing this in your query SELECT groups.*, you are already getting group data along with ID , what else do you want

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple join between the `groups` and `forums` tables and a group by on the group id and count the number of records:

```
select groups.id, count(*) as forum_count
from groups
left join forums on groups.id = forums.group_id
group by groups.id
```

If you would like to get all fields from the `groups` table, not just the id, then on MySQL v5.7 and above you can use the following statement because all field value within the `groups` table are functionally dependent on the `id` field:

```
select groups.*, count(*) as forum_count
from groups
left join forums on groups.id = forums.group_id
group by groups.id
```

In earlier versions, if full group by sql mode is enabled, you need to use a subquery or list all fields from the `groups` table in the group by list:

```
select groups.*, count(*) as forum_count
from groups
left join forums on groups.id = forums.group_id
group by groups.id,... --list all fields from the groups table here
```

Comment: what if I want to place a condition and check that this group id and user_id not exist in group members table can you answer here or should I post another question ?

Comment: All new questions should be asked as a new question. You can refer back to this question in the new one.